# How to set border for message in QMessageBox?

Tags: html, css, qt, qmessagebox

I tried to set border for my message but it does not work. Can you guys point out where the problem is?

```
QMessageBox msg(this);
msg.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
msg.setWindowTitle(QLatin1String("Notice"));
msg.setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
msg.setText("<html><head/><body><p>The reason of error is :</p><p><span style=\"border : 1px solid;\"><i> There is no data </i></span></p></body></html>");
msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
msg.setIcon(QMessageBox::Icon::Warning);
msg.exec();
```

This is the result, italic works but border does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Supported HTML Subset](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) of Qt
Try to use `border-color` and `border-style`
You can also put the text *`"There is no data"`* in another QLabel and use

```
yourReasonLabel.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;");
```

Or replace your `span` by a `table` and add `css`:

```
msg->setText("<html><head/><body>"
             "<p>The reason of error is :</p>"
             "<table style='border-style: solid; border-color: orange;border-width: 1px;'>"
             "<tr><td><i> There is no data </i></td></tr>"
             "</table></body></html>");
```

Comment: thank you. I tried to use `border-style` but it does not work. And I don't know how to set pixel for border, there is no `border-width`.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought about that but I still don't know how to add a label into `msg` in this case

Comment: @gnase, You can subclass ```QDialog``` to make your own ```MessageBox```

Comment: OK, it works now. Thank you! I have same idea, but did not refresh this page, so did not see your update. :). accepted answer.